# How to write stored procedure that used functions and sends parameters to functions

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, output

I need to write stored proc that gets a value from one table. Calculate new value according the retrieved value and sends the new value to a function.

I have the following SQL statement:

```
select mid from lastmid where region = '12'
```

Then I need to send this mid as a parameter to a function

The function will generate new mid in the following fashion:

1. Get last 7 characters of mid and convert them to integer and increment that integer by 1
2. I need to get New Sequence(Paded With 0's to give 7 Digits) With the 1st 9 Digits from the OLD mid

and output the result

How can I do it?

Comment: what have you done so far ?

Comment: I have selected initial mid value, got the last 7 numbers. Now I'm working on a 2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
left(mid ,9) +  right('0000000' + cast(YourFunction(mid) as varchar), 7) as NewMid
```

Or, you could do it all in one line:

```
left(mid ,9) + right('0000000' + cast(cast(right(mid, 7) as int) + 1 as varchar), 7) as NewMid
```